# I can't connect to other machines within the same network

Tags: networking, localhost, apache2

I'm developing a portal and the main aim for this portal is for all my colleagues (whose machines are connected to the same network) to access the portal.

I have tried to reinstall my apache server and it still gives me the same error.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04

I have limited knowledge when it comes to networks and any help will be really great.

[This is the supposed output when another machine typed the ip address of my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXcEL.png)

I installed virtualbox and tried to test the problem when I open the google chrome and firefox in the virtual box i get this messages:

```
Firefox:

Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at xxx.xxx.xx.240.

The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Chrome:

This site can't be reached
xxx.xxx.xx.240 is unreachable
ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

I even tried to acess my portal using a machine that has windows as its os it it gives me this error:

Chrome on windows:

This site can't be reached
xxx.xxx.xx.240 took too long to respond
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

EDIT:
As per Tomer Petel's suggestion here is the ifconfig of my vm: (and since all of our machines here in the office are linux based, I'm using ubuntu for my vm as well)

```
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:99:fb:5d  
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.60.xxx  Bcast:192.168.60.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4463:ae0a:747e:8737/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:98 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12438 (12.4 KB)  TX bytes:7435 (7.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:13471 (13.4 KB)  TX bytes:13471 (13.4 KB)
```

and here is the ifconfig of my machine (w/c is the server for the portal)

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:5c:8e:98:c8:51  
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.60.xxx  Bcast:192.168.60.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4764:697e:9305:12b5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1171474 errors:0 dropped:12 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:735472 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1405120963 (1.4 GB)  TX bytes:82457324 (82.4 MB)

enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:f2:6d:06:69:72  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1552 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1552 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:4176664 (4.1 MB)  TX bytes:4176664 (4.1 MB)
```

```
`I tried netstat -an | grep ':80'
tcp        0      0 192.168.60.250:35724    23.111.228.220:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.60.250:35728    23.111.228.220:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.60.250:35740    23.111.228.220:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.60.250:35732    23.111.228.220:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.60.250:35726    23.111.228.220:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.60.250:35730    23.111.228.220:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 192.168.60.250:80       192.168.60.250:34430    TIME_WAIT  `
```

Comment: It looks like your web server is not online. Please try to enter the portal from the server itself by entering the address of the localhost (127.0.0.1)

Comment: For clarification. Instead of my ip address I will enter 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes, that's the loopback address. It should work on the server itself before trying to access it from remote machines.

Comment: @TomerPetel. Hello! I tired your suggestion. as expected when I tried it on the server itself it works. but when I tried it in my vm it throws an error

Comment: That's good. Now paste here the server's 'ifconfig' and the 'ipconfig' (supposed it's Windows) of a remote machine that you try to access the site from. We need to verify that they are on the same subnet

Comment: @TomerPetel ok. I will just add those in my question. thanks!

Comment: thanks for posting the network configuration. We can try to get the VM to work but that's a different issue since it uses a virtual network adapter and more configuration need to be done. you can read more on this [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/network_configure_ws.html). I would verify that the same IP/Subnet (addr:192.168.60.xxx/255.255.255.0) is configured in one of your colleagues computer. if it does configured try and ping from the remote comp to the server. If it's all good then something is blocking the incoming port 80 on your server

Comment: the configuration of the vm is not important because my main goal is for my portal to be accessible for all my colleagues :) and I can ping from my pc and vice versa.

May I ask how to know if something is blocking the port 80?

Comment: You can use the `telnet` application to determine if the port is open. install `telnet` on the remote machine (sudo apt-get install telnetd -y
). submit the command: `telnet <web_server_ip_addr> 80`.If you're not getting the message _telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused_ then it's open. if it's open then your server is not working on 80, if not then something is blocking the port (Software FW, HW FW although it'll not usually be when working in the same network)

Comment: @Tomer Petel and I don't believe firewalls exist in our networks because I can access other locally hosted websites in our network. Either in my pc or my vm. This problem had been bugging me for months now lmao

Comment: Try the `telnet` and share the results

Comment: @TomerPetel i tried telnet in my vm and this is what I got : 
I inputted `telnet xxx.xxx.xx.xxx 80` and this is the result: Trying `xxx.xxx.xx.xxx...` `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host`

Comment: So you're not on the same network apparently - the remote computer doesn't know how to get to the server. Check that they both on the same physical network (connected to the same switch on the **same** Vlan) and verify the they are sharing the same subnet mask (i.e 192.168.60.X/255.255.255.0)

Comment: @TomerPetel as you can see on my recent edit on my post. the vm and my pc have the same subnet mask. Is there any other way to let my vm or any other machine connected to .60 recognize my pc?

Comment: As I said the VM requires more configuration so let's stick with a physical remote computer. If in the remote computer you're getting `Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host` then they are not on the same subnet. there is nothing you need to do since it's being handled by the ARP protocol. Just connect the server and remote machine to the same switch (on the same VLAN), give them the same Subnet mask and it should work.

Comment: @TomerPetel I just wanna say thanks for being patient in answering my questions. this is just weird but I changed the ip address of my server then reinstalled my ssh/sshd, then suddenly I can access my portal from my vm and every machine here in our office. Like I said thanks again

Comment: You welcome. Good job - happy to hear you were able resolve the issue.

Comment: @TomerPetel this is just so weird. I just restarted my machine. then when I tried to access my portal thru my vm again. The error returned *facepalm

Comment: Make sure you configured the network adapter correctly, not via `ifconfig` - you need to edit  `/etc/network/interfaces` for it to be persistent over restarts.

Comment: @TomerPetel can you provide an example of what to edit in `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: @TomerPetel I tried `netstat -an | grep ':80'` but I don't know what to make of the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, it was web server IP configuration issue. 
You'll need to configure the web server's IP via `/etc/network/interfaces` and not via `ifconfig` since it's not persistent over reboots. See how to [here](https://www.swiftstack.com/docs/install/configure_networking.html)

Comment: I tried. then rebooted my pc. but the problem sadly persists.

Comment: See [here](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3353039/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-on-linux.html) how to config your 'enp3s0' interface

Comment: I will mark this as answered as I just configured it. and now everything works. Thank you so much